# Ruby - Pick one element from array by possibility

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array with 3 elements and I want to pick one and add that into another array base on possibility.

For example, num 1 has 5% chance to be picked, num 2 has 60% chance to be picked and num 3 has 35% chance to be picked.

```rb
arr = [{:num=>1, :diff=>-29}, {:num=>2, :diff=>5}, {:num=>3, :diff=>25}]
```

I found below methods from stackoverflow, just wondering if this would work? Or there is another way to do it?

```rb
def get_num(arr)
    case rand(100) + 1
    when 1..5
        p arr[0]
    when 6..65
        p arr[1]
    when 66..100
        p arr[2]
    end
end

get_num(arr)
```

Thanks!

Comment: @steenslag, It should be 66, I have edited the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine but here are two other approaches.

**Use a cumulative distribution function ("CDF")**

```
CDF = [[0.05,0], [0.05+0.60,1], [0.5+0.60+0.35,2]]
  #=> [[0.05,0], [0.65,1], [1.0,2]]
```

```
def get_num(arr)
  n = rand
  arr[CDF.find { |mx,_idx| n <= mx }.last]
end
```

```
arr = [{:num=>1, :diff=>-29}, {:num=>2, :diff=>5}, {:num=>3, :diff=>25}]
```

```
get_num(arr)
  #=> {:num=>2, :diff=>5}
get_num(arr)
  #=> {:num=>2, :diff=>5}
get_num(arr)
  #=> {:num=>3, :diff=>25}
get_num(arr)
  #=> {:num=>1, :diff=>-29}
get_num(arr)
  #=> {:num=>2, :diff=>5}
```

Suppose:

```
n = rand
  #=> 0.5385005480168696
```

then

```
a = CDF.find { |mx,_idx| n <= mx }
  #=> [0.65,1]
i = a.last
  #=> 1
arr[i]
  #=> {:num=>2, :diff=>5}
```

Note that I've followed the convention of beginning the name of `find`'s second block variable (`_idx`) with an underscore to signal to the reader that that block variable is not used in the block calculation. Often just an `underscore` (`_`) is used.

Now consider the fraction of times each element of `arr` will be randomly-drawn if `n` draws are made:

```
def outcome_fractions(arr, n)
  n.times
   .with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |_,h| h[get_num(arr)] += 1 }
   .transform_values { |v| v.fdiv(n) }
end
```

**Randomly select from an array of indices**

```
outcome_fractions(arr, 1_000)
  #=> {{:num=>2, :diff=>5}  =>0.612,
  #    {:num=>3, :diff=>25} =>0.328,
  #    {:num=>1, :diff=>-29}=>0.06}
```

```
outcome_fractions(arr, 100_000)
  #=> {{:num=>3, :diff=>25} =>0.34818,
  #    {:num=>1, :diff=>-29}=>0.04958,
  #    {:num=>2, :diff=>5}  =>0.60224}
```

Notice that the fraction of each hash that is randomly drawn approaches its specified population probability as the sample size is increased (though the "pseudo-random" draws are not truly random).

Do not be concerned with how `outcome_fractions` works.

---

Here is another way that is more efficient (because it does not use `find`, which performs a linear search) but uses more memory.

```
CHOICE = [*[0]*5, *[1]*60, *[2]*35]
  #=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  #    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  #    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  #    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
  #    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
  #    2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

```
def get_num(arr)
  arr[CHOICE[rand(100)]]
end
```

```
  #=> {{:num=>2, :diff=>5} =>0.60029,
  #    {:num=>3, :diff=>25}=>0.35022,
  #    {:num=>1, :diff=>-29}=>0.04949}
```

Note that:

```
[*[0]*5, *[1]*60, *[2]*35]
```

produces the same array as

```
[[0]*5, [1]*60, [2]*35].flatten
```

The first `*` in `*[0]*5` is the [splat operator](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/); the second is the method [Array#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2A). `[0]*5 #=> [0,0,0,0,0]` is evaluated first.

`CHOICE` has 100 elements. If the three probabilities were, say, `0.048`, `0.604` and `0.348`, `CHOICE` would have `10**3 #=> 1_000` elements (`48` zeros, `604` ones and `348` twos).

Comment: Thanks Cary! I need to read the first one couple times to make sure I understand it.  And I love how simple it is on method 2.

Comment: I prefer @Stefan's suggestion to use `arr[CHOICE.sample]` rather than `arr[CHOICE[rand(100)]]`, and I would like to draw attention to...

Comment: ...@steenstag's comment on Stefan's answer, which is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small variation / addition to Cary's great answer.

Instead of calculating the cumulative sums yourself, you can let Ruby build it for you out of the initial probabilities:

```
probs = [5, 60, 35]

sum = 0
sums = probs.map { |x| sum += x }
#=> [5, 65, 100]
```

we can now calculate a random number between 0 and the total sum and find the corresponding index:

```
r = rand(sum)                  #=> 37
sums.find_index { |i| r < i }  #=> 1
```

Note that the initial probabilities don't have to sum to 100. instead of `[5, 60, 35]` you could also use:

```
probs = [1, 12, 7]
```

You can wrap the above code into a method:

```
def random_index(*probs)
  sum = 0
  sums = probs.map { |x| sum += x }
  r = rand(sum)
  sums.find_index { |i| r < i }
end

random_index(5, 60, 35) #=> 1
random_index(5, 60, 35) #=> 1
random_index(5, 60, 35) #=> 2
```

You could also make the method return a proc / lambda that can be reused:

```
def random_index_proc(*probs)
  sum = 0
  sums = probs.map { |x| sum += x }
  -> {
    r = rand(sum)
    sums.find_index { |i| r < i }
  }
end

prc = random_index_proc(5, 60, 35)

prc.call #=> 1
prc.call #=> 1
prc.call #=> 0
```

Last not least, you can also pre-populate an array this way: (using Cary's naming convention)

```
CHOICE = [5, 60, 35].flat_map.with_index { |v, i| [i] * v }
```

and get a random element via:

```
def get_num(arr)
  arr[CHOICE.sample]
end
```

To keep the array small, you should prefer `[1, 12, 7]` (20 elements) over `[5, 60, 35]` (100 elements). With a little help from [`gcd`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#gcd-method) you don't even have to calculate it yourself:

```
probs = [5, 60, 35]

gcd = probs.reduce { |a, b| a.gcd(b) }
#=> 5

probs.map { |i| i / gcd }
#=> [1, 12, 7]
```

Comment: When there are a lot of initial propabilities  you could even do `sums.bsearch_index { |i| r < i } ` for a binary search.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your detailed explanation! I am gonna try it out on my project :) Thanks!